# Passing additional arguments using scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy

I am writing a program in Python that will fit Gaussian and Lorentzian shapes to some given resonance data. I originally began using `scipy.optimize.leastsq` but changed to using `optimize.curve_fit` after having difficulties in retrieving the errors in the optimized parameters from the covariance matrix.

I have defined a function to fit a sum of Gaussian and Lorentzian:

```
def mix(x,*p):
    ng = numg
    p1 = p[:3*ng]
    p2 = p[3*ng:]
    a = sumarray(gaussian(x,p1),lorentzian(x,p2))
    return a
```

where `p` is an array of the initial guesses at the fit parameters. Here is the instance where it is called using `curve_fit`:

```
leastsq,covar = opt.curve_fit(mix,energy,intensity,inputtot)
```

At the moment `numg` (the number of Gaussian shapes) is a global variable. Is there's any way that it can be incorporated into `curve_fit` as an extra argument instead, as can be done with `leastsq`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The great thing about python is that you can define functions that return other functions,
try currying:

```
def make_mix(numg): 
    def mix(x, *p): 
        ng = numg
        p1 = p[:3*ng]
        p2 = p[3*ng:]
        a = sumarray(gaussian(x,p1),lorentzian(x,p2))
        return a
    return mix
```

and then

```
leastsq, covar = opt.curve_fit(make_mix(numg),energy,intensity,inputtot)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing an inner closure, you may also curry using [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```py
leastsq, covar = opt.curve_fit(
    partial(mix, numg=my_constant),
    # ...
)
```