# Passing list of lists as input to scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I am trying to solve an example marketing mix model problem using python and the curve_fit function.

I need to fit two sets of parameters, which i add to my function as a * arg list of lists. I can get the curve fit to work for one set of parameter (a single list) but not two.

## Code

```
#import packages
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.filters.filtertools import recursive_filter as rec
```

### Dataset

```
a = np.array(0).repeat(150)
b = np.array(0).repeat(150)
c = np.array(0).repeat(150)
a[0:90] = np.random.uniform(5,10,(90,))
b[50:150] = np.random.uniform(20,40,(100,))
c[30:100] = np.random.uniform(5,25,(70,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,'c':c})
```

## Fitting one set of parameters

```
def mmm(data,*param):
    dic = {}
    j = 0
    for i in data:
        dic[i] = rec(data[i],param[j])
        j += 1
    return(np.sum(pd.DataFrame(dic),1))
```

The function, applies the recursive filter to each field in the data argument with a different lambda parameter and returns the dataframe row sum.

```
kpi = mmm(df,*(0.5,0.5,0.1)) + np.random.uniform(-5,5)
```

When passing a *argument to the scipy curve fit function you have to define a function that outputs a function. As described here:[Pass tuple as input argument for scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326524/pass-tuple-as-input-argument-for-scipy-optimize-curve-fit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

### Fit the curve

```
a = np.zeros(3)
def make_func():
    def mmm(data,*param):
        dic = {}
        j = 0
        for i in data:
            dic[i] = rec(data[i],param[j])
            j += 1
        return(np.sum(pd.DataFrame(dic),1))
    return(mmm) 
leastsq, covar = curve_fit(make_func(),df,kpi,a)

print(leastsq)
array([0.87560795, 0.87192766, 0.84864161])
```

## Fitting two sets of parameters

```
def mmm(x,*arg):
    c = args[0]
    a = args[1]
    dic = {}
    j = 0
    for i in x:
        dic[i] = c[j] * rec(x[i], a[j])
        j += 1
    return(np.sum(pd.DataFrame(dic),1))
```

The function, applies the recursive filter to each field in the data argument with a different lambda (a), multiplies it by a scalar (c) and takes the row sum of the dataframe.

```
args = [[4,5,3],[0.2,0.4,0.5]]
kpi = mmm(df,*args) + np.random.uniform(-5,5)
```

### Fit the curve

```
args = np.zeros(6)
def make_func():
    def mmm(x,*args):
        c = args[0]
        a = args[1]
        dic = {}
        j = 0
        for i in x:
            dic[i] = c[j] * rec( x[i], a[j])
            j += 1
        return(np.sum(pd.DataFrame(dic),1))
    return(make_func)
leastsq, covar = curve_fit(make_func,df, kpi, p0=args)
```

Using the same method as for one list of parameters spits out an error for two. The error is as follows:

```
TypeError: make_func() takes 0 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

Is there something else, i have to do in order to get this code working?

Cheers,

Comment: Try putting parenthesis `()` after `make_func` in the last line. Your error is not reproducible because we don't know what `df` is

Comment: I updated the above to include the df dataframe.

Comment: Typo: In the function definition `def mmm(x,*arg):` after the heading "Fitting two sets of parameters", it should be `*args` and not `*arg`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things which looks to me the source of error.

1) In the last part where you fit the curve in the function `make_func()`, you are returning the function itself. If I compare it to the previous function definition, I think it should be `return(mmm)`.

2) `args = np.zeros(6)` results in an array of zeros which you pass as an argument to `make_func()`. You then assign `c = args[0]` and `a = args[1]` so basically `c=0` and `a=0` which are scalar variables. Now in the `mmm(x,*args):` function you use `dic[i] = c[j] * rec( x[i], a[j])`. Here pops up the `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.` because `a` and `c` are scalars but you are using index operations on them.

Comment: Thanks, I ironed out all these errors but the code still doesn't work. Have you managed to get the curve fit to work?